# Получение нумерованных данных по группам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть основная таблица: `Section(id,Name)`

Вторичные таблицы:

1. `Remarks(id,RemarkText,SendDate)`
2. `SectionRemark(id, refSection,refRemark, RemarkTextEdited)`

Собираюсь создать вьюху `Section_RemarkView` где можно получать список по группировке `Section` с нумерациями + Cортировка по `Remarks.SendDate`,`SectionRemark.id`

Пример 1:

```sql
Select * from Section_RemarkView where refSection=22
```

Результат:

| Num | id | refSection | RemarkText | SendDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 22 | Замечания 1 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | 1002 | 22 | Замечания 2 | 2022-12-03 |
| 3 | 1006 | 22 | Замечания 5 | 2022-12-05 |
| 4 | 1003 | 22 | Замечания 3 | NULL |
| 5 | 1004 | 22 | Замечания 4 | NULL |

Пример 2:

```sql
Select * from Section_RemarkView where refSection in (10,22)
```

Результат:

| Num | id | refSection | RemarkText | SendDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 | 10 | Замечания 11 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | 901 | 10 | Замечания 22 | 2022-12-02 |
| 3 | 903 | 10 | Замечания 44 | 2022-12-03 |
| 4 | 902 | 10 | Замечания 33 | NULL |
| 1 | 1001 | 22 | Замечания 1 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | 1002 | 22 | Замечания 2 | 2022-12-03 |
| 3 | 1006 | 22 | Замечания 5 | 2022-12-05 |
| 4 | 1003 | 22 | Замечания 3 | NULL |
| 5 | 1004 | 22 | Замечания 4 | NULL |

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, как составить SQL-запрос вьюхи чтобы получить такой результат?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем вам вообще вьюха? всё делается простым запросом из одной таблички. Если нужна индексированная вьюха - просто добавьте индекс в табличку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос вьюхи:

```sql
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY refSection ORDER BY ISNULL(r.SendDate, GETDATE()) ASC, sr.id ASC) AS int) AS RowNumber
    , sr.id
    , ISNULL(sr.RemarkTextEdited, r.RemarkText) AS RemarkText
    , sr.refSection
    , r.SendDate
FROM SectionRemark sr
LEFT JOIN Remarks r ON r.id = sr.refRemark
```